# How to theme a select box with multiple selection enabled

Tags: 7, forms

I have a select box with multiple selection option enabled in my custom form. Everything is works fine, however the problem is the appearance is not good and also If I have more options then the selection becomes difficult.

Is there any module out there which offers left-right selection widget like below
[image]

or any other better solution which offers better user friendly selection for select box with multiple selection option enabled.

Hope there is an easy way to achieve this rather than writing custom CSS, jQuery/JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are looking for this [Multi Select](http://drupal.org/project/multiselect) module.

> The Multiselect module defines a widget to be used with CCK fields. It
>   allows the user to select multiple items in an easy way. It consists
>   of two lists, one of all available items, the other of selected items.
>   The user can select an item by moving it from the unselected list to
>   the selected list. This module relies on the built-in jQuery features
>   of Drupal and does not require any additional modules other than the
>   CCK module set (Drupal 7 version has no dependencies).

Comment: This module has FAPI support too :)

Answer (score 2):

The [Improved Multi Select](http://drupal.org/project/improved_multi_select) widget sounds right up your street:

> The Improved Multi Select module replace the default multi-select boxes with two pannel list and search.
>
> The first panel holds the options that are available, and the second panel holds the options that have been selected.

It looks pretty good too:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Other than the modules listed above, here is the few others,

1. [jQuery UI Multiselect](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_ui_multiselect)
2. [Multiple selects](http://drupal.org/project/multiple_selects)

   [image]
3. [Chosen](http://drupal.org/project/chosen)

   [image]